# obtener valores de JSON en mysql

Tags: mysql, json

se me ocurrió hacer una tabla con JSON, pero el problema es cuando puse un campo con una matriz de datos numerica.
Como puedo hacer un SQl para obtener por ejemplo el valor ddel campo precio o direccion, mil gracias.

Esto es lo que tengo en la tabla en MySql, la columna se llama informacion

informacion

```
{
    "5": {
        "label": "Precio Previsto",
        "value": "150",
        "type": "text"
    },
    "6": {
        "label": "Direccion y Detalles",
        "value": "PLAZA COMERCIAL REFORMA 222",
        "type": "text-area"
    },
    "7": {
        "label": "Horario Base",
        "value": "18:00",
        "type": "radio"
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm la verdad yo veo que guardar una columna con datos JSON para despues obtener un dato del mismo es algo mal planteado, deberias tener una tabla donde tengas varias columnas con los datos del JSON. ;)

Comment: busca documentación de la función JSON_EXTRACT

Comment: el problema es que es un campo donde vas agregando opciones según las características y es una opción dinámica :(

Answer (score 0):

Dado que tienes una estructura definida (label, value, type) te conviene convertir tal json en una tabla usando la función [`json_table()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table):

```
SELECT t.label
     , t.value
  FROM tutabla x
     , json_table( x.informacion
                 , '$.*'
                   COLUMNS( 
                     label VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.label'
                   , value VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.value'
                   )
                 ) as t
  WHERE t.label like 'Precio%'
```

Cuyo resultado sería algo como:

```
+-----------------+-------+
| label           | value |
+-----------------+-------+
| Precio Previsto | 150   |
+-----------------+-------+
```

Puedes verlo en acción en [este fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ux2T5ipQ9wfFxfhYc8KdgU/0).

Answer (score 0):

[Sal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16228/sal) dio la respuesta correcta, pero cabe comentar dos cosas:

1. El uso del JSON PATH propuesto es para **extraer datos desde un objeto que es una colección de llaves y objetos**

Noten el uso del JSON PATH `$.*` en la solución de Sal. Dado que contenido de `informacion` es un objeto, ese JSON PATH le está diciendo a JSON_TABLE: "tus filas son los valores asociados a cada una de las llaves".

2. Si en cambio hubiera que **extraer datoa desde un array de objetos**, digamos, si el contenido  de `informacion`  fuese un array:

_

```
[
     {
        "label": "Precio Previsto",
        "value": "150",
        "type": "text"
    },
      {
        "label": "Direccion y Detalles",
        "value": "PLAZA COMERCIAL REFORMA 222",
        "type": "text-area"
    },
      {
        "label": "Horario Base",
        "value": "18:00",
        "type": "radio"
    }
]
```

El JSON PATH equivalente sería `$[*]`  o sea "tus filas son cada uno de los items del array". Salvo por ese JSON PATH, la consulta se ve casi igual

```
select t.* from tabla_info ,  json_table(tabla_info.informacion,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                      label VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.label'
                      , value VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.value'
                      )
           ) as t
```